# Residues of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a meromorphic function and $n$ is a positive integer.
Find the residue of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ at $z=a$ if
a. $a$ is a zero of order $n$ of the function $f$
b. $a$ is a pole of order $n$ of the function $f$.

I think for part b, the answer is zero since if $a$ is a pole of order $n$ for $f$, then $a$ is a pole of order $n-1$ for $f'$.
Then $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ has a zero of order $1$ so the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ will be $0$.

However, I'm unsure how to do part $a$.
$$\int_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \ dz$$
where $C$ is the circle with centre $a$, radius $R>0$.

So
$$\mathrm{Res}(g,0) = \lim_{z\to a}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}(z-a)^n$$

Comment: $f'$ has a pole of order $n+1$. Indeed zeros are just poles of negative order so b) answers a)

Comment: Use argument principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle